# How can you test for http config options in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, http

In this service method I want to test for the presence of the skipAuthorization setting.

```
    var register = function (registration) {
        logout();
        return $http({
            url: apiUrl + 'api/account/register',
            method: 'POST',
            data: registration,
            skipAuthorization: true
        });
    };
```

Using $httpBackend, I can inspect the data and the headers, but I can't find any documentation related to the optional config object.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I'm not thrilled with the solution below, but it does test the scenario in a round-about way.

```
        it('should flag the interceptor to skip authorization', function () {
            spyOn(my_store, 'get').and.returnValue('foo');
            service.register();
            http.expectPOST(url, undefined, function (headers) {
                //If we don't skip authorization, this header would be "Bearer foo"
                return headers['Authorization'] === undefined;
            });
            http.flush();
        });
```

This works because if I *don't* set skipAuthorization to true, I will see a bearer token on the request headers. It relies on the fact that my interceptor pulls the token out of local storage, which I have mocked with a Jasmine spy (my_store).

Comment: What is skipAuthorization? It's not documented. What effect does it have?

Comment: It is a custom flag to one of my http interceptors. Tells the interceptor to skip adding a certain header to the request. The thing I want to test is that my register call sets that flag -- most calls do not.